# Extending routerLink in angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives, angular2-router3

How can I extend the `[routerLink]` directive from the Angular Router v3 so I can wrap some custom functionality myself? I've taken a look at the [`RouterLinkWithHref`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_link.ts) directive and it appears that is what I want to extend, so I produced this:

### ExtendedRouterLinkDirective

```
import {Directive, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterLinkWithHref} from "@angular/router";
import {Model} from "../Classes/Model.class";

@Directive({
    selector: 'a[extendedRouterLink]'
})
export class ExtendedRouterLinkDirective extends RouterLinkWithHref {
    @Input('extendedRouterLink') model : Model;

    // Future custom logic
}
```

And I try and use it like so:

```
<a [extendedRouterLink]="model">
```

And I include it in the `directives` array of my component:

```
...
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ExtendedRouterLinkDirective],
...
```

Yet, I get the following runtime error:

> "Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'extendedRouterLink' since it isn't a known native property"

**If I remove the `extends RouterLinkWithHref` from my directive**, it works without errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the exact same issue with angular 2.0.1 did you figure out anything?

Answer (score 3):

I need the same. Using your post, I was able to make it work. Here is what was missing:

```
@Input() mgiRouterLink: string ngOnInit() 

ngOnInit() {
    this.href = this.routerLink = this.mgiRouterLink  
}
```

The parent routeLink directive is expecting this.href and this.routerLink to hold the data from the DOM attribute. Now it look like this:

```
import {Directive, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterLinkWithHref} from "@angular/router";
import {Model} from "../Classes/Model.class";

@Directive({
    selector: 'a[extendedRouterLink]' 
}) 
export class ExtendedRouterLinkDirective extends RouterLinkWithHref {

    @Input() mgiRouterLink: string ngOnInit() 

    ngOnInit() {
        this.href = this.routerLink = this.mgiRouterLink  
    } 
}
```

Comment: routerLinkActive is not working anymore, do you have a clue?

Comment: @FrancisRobitaille I had same problem. Angular v8 implements RouterLinkActive such way, that it expects RouterLink or RouterLinkWithHref . I guess you could extend RouterLinkActive as well so it would accept your directive.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77607213/5155484 (for href to work on other Angular versions)

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * The url displayed on the anchor element.
     */
    @HostBinding('attr.href') override href: string|null = null;
```

I needed this in order to override the href on Angular 15.
Using the above example from Richard.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/14.0.x/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L353