# Extending a Attribute Directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I would like to extend the built-in `routerLink` directive to create my own directive called `customRouterLink`.

I have simply created a class that extends `RouterLinkWithHref`:

```
@Directive({ 
     selector: 'a[customRouterLink]'
})
export class CustomLinkDirective extends RouterLinkWithHref {

  constructor(router: Router, route: ActivatedRoute, locationStrategy:  LocationStrategy) {
    super(router, route, locationStrategy);
  }

  @Input()
  set customRouterLink(data: any[]|string) {
      console.log("custom directive input", data);
  }

}
```

I am attempting to create an instance of this directive:

```
<a [customRouterLink]="'http://www.google.com'">custom link</a>
```

Which is causing the following error:

```
Can't bind to 'customRouterLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.
```

However, if I remove `extends RouterLinkWithHref` from the directive definition it works.

Example plunkers:

- `CustomLinkDirective extends RouterLinkWithHref` - [Shows error above](https://plnkr.co/edit/BmxmD35KzJtwaX3DjwnX?p=preview)
- `CustomLinkDirective` not extending `RouterLinkWithHref` - [Directive created without error](https://plnkr.co/edit/4PgtRtTY54YdOgWeP0TI)

Comment: Did you solve this in the end? Was looking at doing something similar

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error when attempting to extend the RouterLinkWithHref class. The error is coming from the fact that you do not include an @Input decorator for your directive. You are attempting to pass in your url string `<a [customRouterLink]="'http://www.google.com'">custom link</a>`, but Angular cannot find a property to bind this value to within your class and throws an error. To resolve this simply add `@input('customRouterLink') link: string`.

Answer (score 1):

I did it successfully with

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[customRouterLink]'
})
export class CustomRouterLinkDirective extends RouterLinkWithHref implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    @Input('customRouterLink')
    link: string;

    constructor(
        router: Router,
        route: ActivatedRoute,
        locationStrategy: LocationStrategy
    ) {
        super(router, route, locationStrategy);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.href = this.routerLink = this.link;
    }
}
```

Don't forget you need to register your directive into *app.module.ts*

This is how you can use it

```
 <a [customRouterLink]="/any/any">link</a>
```

Comment: For angular 15 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51828860/5155484 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/77607213/5155484 for the patch

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `CustomLinkDirective` to `declarations` of your module or better create a module for `CustomLinkDirective` and add this module to `imports: [...]` of the module where you want to use your router link.

Comment: I have created a new plunker that includes the `CustomLinkDirective` in the `declarations` of the module, it still doesn't work. Thoughts? https://plnkr.co/edit/8JMdOQ4S1COHOkgA39kT

Comment: Also, note that the directive works fine if it doesn't `extend RouterLinkWithHref `. It's unclear if / why the lack of `declarations` would impact on that.

Comment: Actually, I don't know. But I wonder why it would work at all when not added to `declarations` or did you add it to `directives: []` of the component?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the `directives` of the component

Comment: Any success on extending RouterLinkWithHref?